# Утечка памяти при навигации в UWP приложении

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

Проблема заключается в том, что при навигации внутри `Frame` происходит утечка памяти на 0,5 - 1 мб.

Приложение организовано таким образом:

Есть пару `Page`, по которым происходит навигация. Есть `MainPage`, в котором помещём `SplitView` с кнопками навигации в `SplitView.Pane` и `Frame` помещённым в `SplitView.Content`.

На кнопки навигации навешаны события по типу:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page));
    }
```

При такой организации переходов внутри фрейма, каждый раз создаётся новый объект `Page` и память предыдущего объекта не освобождается. Пробовала задать каждой странице параметр `NavigationCacheMode="Required"` или `NavigationCacheMode="Enable"` В метод `OnNavigatedFrom` помещала `GC.Collect();`. Результат не изменился.

Мой вопрос состоит в том как организовать навигацию таким образом, чтобы предотвратить подобные утечки?

**UPD**

Я погналась за большим числом итераций, чтобы наглядней показать проблему.

```
private void SettingButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (byte i = 0; i < 127; i++)
        {
            Content.Navigate(typeof(Pages.SettingPage));
            MainTextBlock.Text = "Setting";
        }
    }
```

Я попробовала задавать разное число итераций. Наблюдая за диорамой заметила, что в конце цикла сборщик удаляет примерно треть от пикового значения. С повторением цикла происходит незначительное увеличение пика и такое же падение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так нужно же наоборот отключить `NavigationCacheMode`, т.е. установить Disabled (если вам не нужна таким образом работающая кнопка "назад", конечно).

Comment: @Vlad , параметр `Disable` был установлен по умолчанию. Подобными манипуляциями пыталась следовать советам из английской Stack Overflow.

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас реально утечка, а не нормальная работа программы? Если вы повторяете действия в цикле, расход памяти возрастает настолько же с каждой итерацией?

Comment: @VladD, да, вот [снимок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkA87.png) заполнения памяти.

Comment: @ammystr: Ого! А сколько это итераций? И можно привести в вопросе код с итерациями?

Comment: @VladD, привела и указала свои наблюдения.

Comment: Подождите, то есть в конце концов выше определённой границы память не растёт? А можно график с итерациями и пиками?

Comment: Если сборщик мусора может что-то собрать, значит, это не утечка по идее. Утечку он бы не собрал.

Comment: @VladD,  добавила графики.

Comment: @ammystr: Окей, но на графиках вроде бы не видно утечки. Была бы реальная утечка, память бы росла до бесконечности.

Comment: @ammystr: Так что по идее проблемы нету.

Comment: 900 переходов внутри приложения? Мне кажется проблема несколько преувеличена. А что если сделать `SplitView` в качестве `AppShell`?